# Database design for bigger tracking table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am creating a database for a prayer tracker. There are 5 types of prayer for each day. I have a table called `"Types"`

```
id, name
1, Type 1
2, Type 2
3, Type 3
4, Type 4
5, Type 5
```

I want to save records for `each user` against `each prayer` type for each day. Below is my structure for `tracking` table.

```
id, type_id (FK of Types), user_id (FK of user table), date (Y-m-d)
```

I have 500K+ users and for each user there can be max of 5 records against each day. This will be in millions. Basically I want to create an optimized db structure, So it should be faster while doing queries.

- User is login and he should see all records of him/her against each
  day.
- After 1 year, if there are 5 records against each day then for
  500K users, it will be 912,500,000 records. Table will be much
  bigger.
- No. of users are also increasing day by day.

So In order to optimize the database, what will be best practice for above structure of tracking
table?

Comment: *I have a table called "Types"* If this list is static and won't be altered in future (or may be expanded till not more than 64 statuses) than this table seems to be excess. Simply make `type_id` column datatype = SET. This allows to store one row per user per day.

Comment: Which query (top 3) do you want to be fast? (All others could be slow)

Comment: @MichaelKutz User is login and he should see all records of him/her against each day.

Comment: @Akina Types will be only 5, It will never increase.

Comment: When do you remove data? How old? How often?

Comment: I assume their God is watching, so your efforts seem redundant.  Or is that allowing _you_ to play god?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, **912 million records** may seem daunting but it's nothing that regular **indexing** won't be able to handle, especially since your main query is to return only the current day's `prayer types` for the current user which is a very small amount of data. I've managed **Tables** with **10s of billions of rows** in them and proper **indexing** allowed us to return small sets of data in **milliseconds runtime**, on very modest hardware. And I'm sure **Tables** in the **100s of billions** would've been fine as well. Note this was using SQL Server instead of MySQL but the principals are the same on how **indexing** works in regards to storing and fetching data.

At your current rate (no user growth) for example, you wouldn't hit **100 billion rows** for about **100 years**. If you're able to implement Akina's suggestion then you'll be able to cut the amount of data down by 80% too. So that **100 billion rows** now becomes only **20 billion** in **100 years**. (In other words, it withstands the test of time. :) If you're able to archive data after **X number of years** you can also alleviate the data load of your **Table**.

Finally in regards to **indexing** I think to support a query that will select all `prayer type` records for a given user only on a given day, you should create the index on `user_id`, `date` (and depending on which MySQL engine you're using include `type_id` if it's not by default) for best **indexing**.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE blah(
    user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- 3 bytes
    date DATE NOT NULL,  -- 3 bytes
    prayers SET('1','2','3','4','5') NOT NULL,  -- 1 byte
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, date)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

will occupy about 30GB (including overhead).

You may need other indexes, depending on what the queries are.

Comment: Why u don't have ID column which is primary key to table?

user_id is the foreign key of users table, why added as Primary key ?

Comment: @AsfandyarKhan - I am assuming that the _pair_ (user_id, date) is unique, hence acceptable as the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Let's see the other table and the `SELECT` that need `id`.  (It may not actually be needed.)  Two-thirds of the tables that I build have a 'natural' PK and don't really need a surrogate `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Add `id` would increase the table size by _several GB_.